# VB.net .tostring("0.000") from datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am really stuck on this.  I have used numeric string formatting before, but not out of a datagridview.  Any time I try to format a number to "0.000" string from the datagridview it does nothing, just returns the number in the cell unformatted.  Can anyone help correct this?

```
For Each manualprocess In ManualAddOperationsdgv.Rows
        If manualprocess.cells(2).value.ToString = "DRILL" Then
            If lasttool <> manualprocess.cells(4).value.ToString Or lastoffset <> manualprocessoffset Or lastdepth <> manualprocess.cells(10).value Then
                If Not lasttool = 0 Then
                    builder.AppendLine("M9M5M1")
                End If
                builder.AppendLine("")
                builder.AppendLine("N" & blocknumber & "(" & manualprocess.cells(1).value.ToString & " - DRILL OPERATION)")
                blocknumber += 1
                builder.AppendLine("G65P7000T" & manualprocess.cells(4).value.ToString & "M6B#.S" & manualprocess.cells(12).value.ToString & "CC#." & manualprocessoffset & "(D#)")
                builder.AppendLine("G66P7015E" & manualprocess.cells(3).value.ToString & "R.1Q" & manualprocess.cells(14).value.ToString & "Z-" & manualprocess.cells(10).value.ToString("0.0000") & "S" & manualprocess.cells(12).value.ToString & "F" & manualprocess.cells(13).value.ToString("0.0000") & manualprocessoffset) 
            End If
            builder.AppendLine("X" & manualprocess.cells(8).value.ToString("0.000") & "Y" & manualprocess.cells(9).value.ToString("0.000"))
        End If 
Next
```

Comment: What is the value that you want to format? What is the formatted string that you expect to get back and what is your locale setting?

Comment: Maybe sure .value is a Double, maybe it returns a string. I would assume that Option Strict isn't on.

Comment: If I give it a "1" it returns a "1", I need a "1.000".  If I give it "1.5" it returns "1.5" I would like it to be "1.500"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ToString function doesn't know what type of object is in your cell, so try converting your value into a decimal or a double first:

```
Dim decValue As Decimal
If Decimal.TryParse(manualprocess.Cells(8).Value.ToString, decValue) Then
  builder.AppendLine("X" & decValue.ToString("0.000") ...
End If
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it inline?  As you can see there are tons of these.  This was the simplest case I had to copy/paste.

Comment: @user3838112 You could use just the Decimal.Parse function if you are confident the cell *always* has a number in it.  Otherwise, create a simple function.

Comment: It does always have a number in it.  I did not specify that.  I have never used decimal.parse.  Looks promising will try now.